# How to loop on a number

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to loop on a number using jQuery from `1` to `10`. 
Let's say I have

```
var start=8;
var end=13;
```

Expected Output:

> 8 9 10 1 2 3

On reaching `10`, the output series restarts from `1`.

Comment: what is the significance of `13` here

Comment: this will not reach 13

Comment: @SanjeevS yah this is will not reach 13. after in number 10 it will back to the beginning.

Comment: @guradio is it possible, make like that?

Comment: @brk maximum for the iteration.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this looks like homework. If you're trying to learn a new programming language by yourself, start by reading some introductory material about said language.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var start = 8, end = 13;
for(var i = start; i <= end; i++){
    var num = i > 10 ? i % 10 : i;
    console.log(num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var start = 8;
var end = 13;
for(var i = start; i <= end; i++){
  var result = i % 10;
  if(result == 0){
    result = 10;
  }
  console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it is quite straightforward.

```js
var start = 8, end = 13;
for(var i = start; i <= end; i++){
    console.log(i % 10 === 0 ? 10: i % 10);
}
```

Comment: thanks it work. and more simple

Comment: @Gokul Chandrasekaran can you explain this i % 10 === 0 ? 10: i % 10

Answer (score -1):

```js
var start = 5,
  end = 13;

var i = start;

var j = start;
while (j >= start && j < end) {
  console.log(i);

  i = (i + 1) % 10;

  j++;
}
```